# How to make an Auto-hidden Toolbar in iPad app?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, toolbar

I'm new to Xcode development and have a (hopefully simple) question:

I want to write an iPad App which shows a document in an UIPageView and in addition shows a bar at the bottom to navigate in the document (i.e. with buttons on it for each chapter).
This bar should automatically hide (except a small grip) while switching pages and show up when pressing (or dragging) the grip.
The bar should overlap the PageView (PageView not resized).

I already finished the PageView (based on the template in XCode) but don't know the best way to implement the bottom-bar.

Any suggestions?
Examples welcome.

Comment: Be sure to check out apple guide for [Custom View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerPGforiOSLegacy/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html). The thing you want to implement is a "Toolbar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to show

```
[self doSingleViewHideAnimation:myToolBar:kCATransitionFromBottom];


-(void)doSingleViewHideAnimation:(UIView*)incomingView:(NSString*)animType
{   
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:animType];

[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[[incomingView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:kCATransition];
incomingView.hidden = YES;
}
```

To hide

```
[self doSingleViewShowAnimation:myToolBar:kCATransitionFromTop];



-(void)doSingleViewShowAnimation:(UIView*)incomingView:(NSString*)animType
{   
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:animType];

[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[[incomingView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:kCATransition];
incomingView.hidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new view. 
Put a tap gesture recognizer on it
When it's tapped use UIView animations to slide it in or out.

Answer (score 0):

what i found is and also working for me is as under

first i put one toolbar in xib like this

[image]

then create one IBOutlate in .h file like this

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar;
```

then attach it to the toolbar in xib like this

[image]

then i create one `UITapGestureRecognizer` in .m file as below

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handle_Tap:)];
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

and the `handle_Tap:` method is as follow in .m file for sure

```
-(void)handle_Tap:(id)sender
{
    self.toolbar.hidden = !self.toolbar.hidden;
}
```

that's all i need to do and the toolbar is appeared when taped and disappeared when tapped again whola!!

It's done thanks to Apple Documents

Happy Codding !!
Enjoy Day :)